# Managing custom python module dependencies through virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, dependency-management

I am using some custom modules, not available on PyPI. Is it possible to manage the dependency through virtualenv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. `pip` can install packages from -

- PyPI (and other indexes) using requirement specifiers.
- VCS project urls.
- Local project directories.
- Local or remote source archives.

So all you have to do it provide the location of the module from some VCS or local directory in the `requirements.txt` file and `pip install -r requirements.txt` after activating `virtualenv`, and it'll work. More examples can be found at [`pip` documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#examples).

Just keep in mind that pip will run `python setup.py install` after downloading and extracting your custom module. So you must package your module to support that.